# Swift - Moya boolean parameter is always false

Tags: swift, alamofire, moya

I need to make a request via Moya. I've configured my parameters and one of them is of type `Bool`. I've tried casting it to int and even send a literal in the request, but I'm always sending `false` to the server.

Note: If I make the request in Postman or using curl, the request sends the proper boolean value.

EDIT: Code and context-

I'm trying to send a request with a boolean value, so I configured my Target like this:

```
public enum APIBAC {
   ...
  case Foo(NSNumber, String, String, String, Bool)
  ...
}
```

My parameters:

```
  public var parameters: [String: AnyObject]? {
    switch self {
   ...
    case .Foo(_, let data1, let data2, let data3, let boolData):
      return [
        "data1": data1,
        "data2": data2,
        "data3": data3,
        "somethingBool": Int(boolData)
      ]
    default:
      return nil
    }
  }
```

**Problem:
My request is always sending false as the value.**

I've tried by sending the bool value directly with no success.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, please clarify.

Comment: Sorry! I've added code and context there. Thanks.